# how can I create drill down charts using telerik mvc controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

My question is the title itself.
Is there any way to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance .
I am using MVC3 Razor

I am using trial version of telerik controls and downloaded to from telerik site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried, but you can use the OnSeriesClick event to handle the element the user clicked and trying to redirect the user to the next level. More info on [Teleriks documentation site](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-chart-client-api-and-events.html#OnSeriesClick)

Comment: From where I can download the dlls ?

Comment: i used nuget to install telerik mvc extensions, now i got

Comment: they r providing kendo ui dlls